# visual studio code quick open shows only visited files

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just started to use vscode. It seems I can't correctly use Quick open (Control-p). It only shows already visited files. Is there some configuration I need to set to change this behaviour?

I'd like to open them in fuzzy way and I seem to understand that it should be possible but again that doesn't work. My (django) project has 7/8 files named 'models.py' but if I write 'mdl' I don't find anything. Nor it does if I write part of the directory name.

I'm using version 1.18.0-insider

sandro
*:-)

Comment: Solved: it seems it all depended on a wrong pattern in file exclude. I added '**/**.pyc' when the correct pattern was '**/*.pyc'. I realized when searching and an error was raised.

Comment: Please post that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: it seems it all depended on a wrong pattern in file exclude. I added '/.pyc' when the correct pattern was '*/.pyc'. I realized when searching and an error was raised.